# selectOneMenu al seleccionar un campo distinto no lo guarda

Tags: java, primefaces

Tengo un problema con un SelectOneMenu en primefaces, al seleccionar un campo distinto no lo guarda.

```
    <p:selectOneMenu id="listaEmpresas" style="width:100%" value="{pedidosControlador.pedidosBb.empresaSelecionada}" required="true">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione uno" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{pedidosControlador.pedidosBb.listaEmpresas}" var="empresaS" itemLabel="#{empresaS.empresa}"  itemValue="#{empresaS}"/> 
    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres a distinto?

Answer (score -1):

Puedes probar si se envía el valor al backing bean por medio de un 
`<p:ajax event="itemSelect" />`
tambien acostumbro inicializar el objeto relacionado 
`ej. pedidosBb.empresaSelecionada = new empresa();` en el PostConstruct
si te muestra alguna exceptión podes publicarla. saludos..